# How do I send the text in a file discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I have made a .txt file in my work file and it doesn't work when I write
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB9WK.png)

```py
@client.command()
async def readlist():
    await client.say('here you go')
    await client.send_file('blacklist.txt')
```

Comment: Please elaborate more on how does it not working. Also, please type-in the relevant code-snippets ([Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) instead of screenshot

Comment: What do you expect this to do?

Answer (score 0):

[`send_file`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.send_file) requires that a destination be passed as the first parameter (such as a text channel object.)

You would need get the channel object within `readlist` somehow, the easiest way probably being `pass_context=True` in the `command` annotation and adding a parameter to `readlist` for the context object passed. E.g.

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def readlist(ctx):
    # you can now get the channel the command was called in with ctx.message.channel
```